# Dropzone.js sends empty files

Tags: laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone with Laravel and no other threads about this problem have solved my issue.

Currently I load dropzone.js from a cdn.

And, as told in their doc, I just use these lines where I had to include the token with Laravel:

```
<form
    action="{{ route('store_photo_path',['zip' => $flyer->zip, 'street' => $flyer->street]) }}"
    class="dropzone"
>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

On my PhotoController, the token arrives right so data is being recieved, but file is totally empty, so I can't manipulate the images. Here is the AJAX response (Laravel's Request object type):

```
{"_token":"Ng24JDmKn3ylX6p5sFmFvgDcsLp983BZ8IL7pXIN","file":{}}
```

I'm not using any kind of jQuery method or extending Dropzone behaviour, just trying to make it work in the most simple way Dropzone says it should work. I've checked including enctype does not work because removes the file object and Dropzone does not include it in their documentation, and you shouldn't include more input fields based on their documentation again.

Also, $_POST var has the same information (just the token and the file object empty).

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem with this.

Comment: Damn dropzone library. Same problem. @Joss did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form, which allows file uploads.

Comment: Including `enctype="multipart/form-data"` has no effect, checked again with that. Dropzone attachs that attribute out of the box.